# Clearing a log file which is in use

Tags: .net, python, file-io, file-permissions

On my job, I am working with a big .NET application which writes to a log file. Let's call the application `CompanyApplication`. I have written a simple Python script which clears the log:

```
file_object = open('C:\\log.txt', 'w')
file_object.write("")
file_object.close()
```

When `CompanyApplication.exe` is not running this works fine. However, when `CompanyApplication.exe` is running I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "deleteLog.py", line 1, in <module>
>   file_object = open('C:\log.txt', 'w')
>   IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\log.txt'

This must be because `CompanyApplication` holds a lock on the log file. Is there any way I can "unlock" the log file, clear it, and then "hand the lock back" to `CompanyApplication`? I would prefer a solution which could be automated (that's why I wrote the Python script in the first place).

Additional info: There is only so much I can do to change `CompanyApplication` itself. I am using Windows XP Pro. I have administrator privileges.

Comment: I guess handling `SIGHUP` is out then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fill out the FileShare parameter for the open call on the log file in your .NET program.

Specifically you will want to [allow read/write sharing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx).

Depending on how your .NET application works when writing to the log though, what you are suggesting might not work as expected and may cause problems with the .NET program.

You could simply start a thread in the .NET program which creates an event and waits on it.  Later you can set that event from your Python program and the .NET will safely clear it's own log file and reset the event.

Comment: Is there an equivalent way to set a FileShare type parameter when opening a file handle in Python on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the output to the file is buffered, so even if you could take over the file and empty it, you would not be able to empty the buffer in the running program. The result would either be a partial entry at the beginning of the file, or that the program continues to write at the previous position which would fill everything up to that point with garbage.

To be able to empty the log while the application is running, the logging in the application has to be rewritten. It has to only open the log file when needed, and close it after writing to it. That way your script can attempt to clear the file, and if it fails it can wait a moment and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

No. As you said, CompanyApplication has a **lock** on the file. What would be the point of a lock if any other application can unlock it at any time?

Comment: Well, at the end of the day both CompanyApplication and the Python script have been launched by me, a human being with adminstrator privileges.